# Summing the sub values of an indexed hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

so I'm working on a project where I have a hash as follows:

```
{ 1=>{:id=>133, 
     :total=>#<BigDecimal:cc08558,'0.41323E3',18(18)>}, 
  2=>{:id=>134, 
      :total=>#<BigDecimal:cc082b0,'0.523E1',18(18)>}, 
  6=>{:id=>166, 
      :total=>#<BigDecimal:cbdbb98,'0.837E2',18(18)>}, 
  8=>{:id=>168, 
      :total=>#<BigDecimal:cbdb8a0,'0.72236E3',18(18)>}, 
  9=>{:id=>169, 
      :total=>#<BigDecimal:cbdb738,'0.132E3',9(18)>} }
```

and I want to add element to this hash that has the sum of all the total values in the hash. With the result being as follows:

```
{ 1=>{:id=>133, 
     :total=>#<BigDecimal:cc08558,'0.41323E3',18(18)>}, 
  2=>{:id=>134, 
      :total=>#<BigDecimal:cc082b0,'0.523E1',18(18)>}, 
  6=>{:id=>166, 
      :total=>#<BigDecimal:cbdbb98,'0.837E2',18(18)>}, 
  8=>{:id=>168, 
      :total=>#<BigDecimal:cbdb8a0,'0.72236E3',18(18)>}, 
  9=>{:id=>169, 
      :total=>#<BigDecimal:cbdb738,'0.132E3',9(18)>},
  0=>{:id=>000,
      :total=><whatever the total is>} }
```

but I'm having some trouble getting this done at the moment I have:

```
month_hash.each.sum(:total)
```

But this doesn't seem to be doing what I want.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`values`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-values) to get all your sub-hashes, and use [`inject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) to iterate over the hashes and sum the totals :

```
sum = h.values.inject(0){|sum,h| sum + h[:total] }
h[0] = {:id => 0, :total => sum}
```

`h` is now :

```
{1=>{:id=>133, :total=>413.23},
 2=>{:id=>134, :total=>5.23},
 6=>{:id=>166, :total=>83.7},
 8=>{:id=>168, :total=>722.36},
 9=>{:id=>169, :total=>132.0},
 0=>{:id=>0, :total=>1356.52}}
```

Note that if you run it again, you'll have added sum twice :

```
{1=>{:id=>133, :total=>413.23},
 2=>{:id=>134, :total=>5.23},
 6=>{:id=>166, :total=>83.7},
 8=>{:id=>168, :total=>722.36},
 9=>{:id=>169, :total=>132.0},
 0=>{:id=>0, :total=>2713.04}}
```